# Check Queue Name in Formula

Tags: formula, escalation

Is it possible to reference a queue by name within a case escalation formula?  Salesforce throws an error that looks like the view source of an entire web page when I try to use either of these to check a queue name:

**Owner:Queue.QueueName** or **Owner:Queue.DeveloperName**

I know I can check by Id, but I'd prefer to avoid going that route if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: I think they might have changed it so `Owner.Name` works now, but not sure.

Comment: you get the error at escalation time?  You might need your formula to first check if case is owned by a queue before evaluating the queue name = x